# GitVersion not respecting tag-prefix

Tags: git, gitversion

The Background:

I have a Git repository with random tags for various things however when our pipeline runs we execute GitVersion to calculate the version number for a nuget package in the solution. Tags such as '2023.02.28' and 'random-text'. I'd like GitVersion to only consider tags that start with V to simplify things with the nuget package.

The Problem:

GitVersion is not using the `tag-prefix` setting (or I'm using it wrong) and is instead taking a more recent tag, 2023.02.28, instead of the desired tag, v2.0.9.

I've tried setting `tag-prefix` to the following variations to no avail

- tag-prefix: ^[vV]\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}
- tag-prefix: '^[vV]\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}'
- tag-prefix: ^[vV]+
- tag-prefix: '^[vV]+'
- tag-prefix: '[vV]'
- tag-prefix: 'v'

as well as many other "throw **** at the wall and see what sticks" formats.

I'm really stuck here because even according to the [documentation](https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/configuration#global-configuration)

> A regex which is used to trim Git tags before processing (e.g., v1.0.0). Default is [vV], although this is just for illustrative purposes as we do a IgnoreCase match and could be v.

It appears this should just be out of the box this should be the way it works.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the tag-prefix works as kind of a filter. It seems to remove the prefix you specify to try to find versions that fit the pattern but it will still pick up stuff that looks like a semantic version if it doesn't have the filter, regardless of the tag-prefix. 

So really what that's doing is trimming off the prefix to see if what's left looks like a SemVer

https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/blob/115f4739a65a491a828c3244287e3b58195d99c1/src/GitVersion.Core/Model/MergeMessage.cs

Comment: Hi @FranciscoGarcia, thanks for getting back to me. After looking into it a bit more you are 100% correct. I was misunderstanding the use of the settings. I've found a work around for my specific use case that I'm going to reply with an answer for so others might find it if they find themselves in the same misunderstanding that i had.

Comment: Actually a better link would be to the SemanticVersion class definition and the TryParse it uses here

https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/blob/115f4739a65a491a828c3244287e3b58195d99c1/src/GitVersion.Core/VersionCalculation/SemanticVersioning/SemanticVersion.cs

Comment: No sweat, I happen to find myself in a very similar predicament and just stumbled across the same answer myself. Good luck, happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a fundamental misunderstanding of how this setting should work. as Francisco pointed out in the comments this is a filter/pattern to remove from tag names before attempting to parse the version.

What this actually means is when you tag a commit as v2.0.1 the tag-prefix is removed prior to GitVersion attempting to parse the value. The default of [vV] in this instance will remove the v and GitVersion will then see 2.0.1.

In my instance I ended up implementing a convention of tag patterns. so for the core application we use `rls/core/[version]` and for the nuget package we use `rls/package/[version]`. So in the GitVersion.yml file set `tag-prefix` to `rls/core/` and when the build script gets the version for the nuget package I use the `overrideconfig` argument `/overrideconfig tag-prefix="rls/package/"`

This seems to be working as desired now. Hopefully this will help some future person that shared the same misunderstanding as I did.